# limit on the number of childProcess.exec() node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm using node.js to spawn multiple phantomjs workers through childProcess.exec and writing the buffer output to DB. I wanted to know the max number of processes that can be spawned via node before node crashes. Phantomjs script is complex which includes logging in and doing stuff, and takes close to 5seconds to return an output.
code looks like this:
`childProcess.exec('./phantomsjs testScript.js', function(err, stdout, stderr){}`

Comment: The maximum number of processes will depend on the machine you're running on and its operating system limits.

Comment: running a centOS with 8 gigs of RAM and intel xeon. Expecting around close to 100 clients per 30 seconds. Hopefully it doesn't die.